# I want to send the live camera frames from jetson to android mobile using usb .how can I do that?

Tags: android, serial-port, usb, serial-communication, usb-otg

I have no knowledge on this part . Is this achievable ,is yes then what kind of cable should I be using to connect android phone to my jetson nano .Will a simple usb otg charger cable which is normally also used for photo or mtp tranfer do?

Comment: This video like article might help. [MaskCam: How to Set Up your NVIDIA Jetson Nano as a Web-Connected Mask Detection Smart Camera](https://youtu.be/Ow4wiGXFJi8)

Comment: he is not using usb communication

Comment: that is unfortunate. However, even if the conditions are not met, there are similar cases, so if you keep looking, you may find something.